# Location polling issue when wifi/3g is off

Tags: android, geolocation

I think I understood that network location polling requires an internet connection in order to retrieve the correct location (lat/lon) associated to the cell towers and wifi networks around. Correct?

Then this is my problem:
I have an app that polls location, and it works fine when wifi/3g is on.
However, when wifi/3g is off, it keeps on giving the last known location (instead of nothing), although I don't ask for the last location fix it in my code. Is there some kind of caching involved and if yes how to ignore it?

Thanks

Comment: I dont think there is internet required for getting location from Network and GPS provider.It will be required in case of location from Wifi

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3145655/340068) will help you

Comment: Thank you Alok. This is the code I am actually using to get my locations (I removed the last known part) but when offline (no internet connection) it keeps on returning the last location

Comment: Are you not able to get location using network and/or GPS ?

Comment: GPS works fine, my problem only concerns network location when the device is offline. I  keep on having the last location returned and I don't understand why since I don't ask for the last known location

Comment: It seems that getting correct location is a tough job in Android.Need to investigate more

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding a check for any connected network before requesting location updates of NETWORK_PROVIDER.

```
public boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
}
```

It's solution for a simple request. If you want to determine when the network is on/off and request/remove location updates, then you must use features of [ConnectivityManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html). It sends broadcast intents when network connectivity changes.